# How do I find a particular sub directory using Ant and then use it to create a symlink?

Tags: ant

I need to create a symlink to a sub-directory using Ant. The issue is that I don't know where the target sub-directory is.

To create a symlink with ant I do this:

```
<symlink link="${parent.dir}/FOO/linkname" resource="${parent.dir}/BAR/target"/>
```

But I don't know what BAR is called in advance so I need to do a search for "target" under parent.dir and then pass the one result into the resource.

Is this possible using fileset? Or another way?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to use a fileset but that might give you several symlinks or none.

A much better approach is to define the path to `BAR` in a property. If there is a dynamic part in this path, change the code so that Ant evaluates the dynamic part and everyone else uses Ant's value.

The typical example here is that the path contains a version or timestamp. Define those in your build file so you can use them everywhere. If a Java process needs the values, pass them to the process as a system property (`-D...`).

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your answer but unfortunately the directory is created by a process outside the Ant sphere.

Comment: Then write a new Ant tasks which puts the path into a property. That allows you to do proper error checking. Writing Ant tasks isn't hard.